# Apache Ignite : ScanQuery giving exception

Tags: java, datagrid, ignite

I am newbie to Apache Ignite. On my windows box, I have started Apache Ignite with double click on ignite.bat file and trying to run following code -

**Cache populating client code**

```
package ignite;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;

public class SpringIgniteClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Run  example!!");
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);

        // Start Ignite in client mode.
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();

        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person>("myStreamCache");
        cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Person.class);

        IgniteCache<Integer, Person> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);


         //for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){ cache.put(i, Integer.toString(i)+"sushil---"); }


        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Person person = new Person(i, i, "name_" + i, (i * 100) % 3000);
            if(person.getSal() < 1000){
                System.out.println(person);
            }
            cache.put(i, person);
        }


    }
}
```

**Cache ScanQuery client code**

```
package ignite;

import javax.cache.Cache.Entry;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.QueryCursor;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.ScanQuery;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate;

public class SpringIgniteReceiverClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Run Receiver example!!");
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);

        // Start Ignite in client mode.
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();

        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person>("myStreamCache");
        cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Person.class);
        IgniteCache<Integer, Person> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);


        IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, Person> filter = new MyIgniteBiPredicate();

        ScanQuery<Integer, Person> query = new ScanQuery<Integer, Person>(filter);
        //query.setLocal(true);
        QueryCursor<Entry<Integer, Person>>  cursor= cache.query(query);
        System.out.println("ALL DATA ->"+cursor.getAll());
    }

}
```

and IgniteBiPredicate implementation is

```
package ignite;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate;

public class MyIgniteBiPredicate implements IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, Person>, Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override public boolean apply(Integer key, Person p) {
        return p.getSal() < 1000;
    }

}
```

**Serialize Java POJO**

```
package ignite;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int age;
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private int sal;

    public Person(int age, int empId, String name, int sal) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.sal = sal;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSal() {
        return sal;
    }

    public void setSal(int sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [age=" + age + ", empId=" + empId + ", name=" + name + ", sal=" + sal + "]";
    }



}
```

During debug, I found that in IgniteCacheProxy.class, following method is called and it is returning null.

```
 /**
     * @param loc Enforce local.
     * @return Local node cluster group.
     */
    private ClusterGroup projection(boolean loc) {
        if (loc || ctx.isLocal() || isReplicatedDataNode())
            return ctx.kernalContext().grid().cluster().forLocal();

        if (ctx.isReplicated())
            return ctx.kernalContext().grid().cluster().forDataNodes(ctx.name()).forRandom();

        return null;
    }
```

And ScanQuery program gives following error.

```
Run Receiver example!!
[21:46:52] (wrn) Default Spring XML file not found (is IGNITE_HOME set?): config/default-config.xml
Mar 05, 2017 9:46:52 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Failed to resolve default logging config file: config/java.util.logging.properties
[21:46:53]    __________  ________________ 
[21:46:53]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[21:46:53]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[21:46:53] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[21:46:53] 
[21:46:53] ver. 1.8.0#20161205-sha1:9ca40dbe
[21:46:53] 2016 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[21:46:53] 
[21:46:53] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[21:46:53] 
[21:46:53] Quiet mode.
[21:46:53]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[21:46:53] 
[21:46:53] OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
[21:46:53] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_65-b17 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.65-b01
[21:46:53] Initial heap size is 124MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[21:46:53] Configured plugins:
[21:46:53]   ^-- None
[21:46:53] 
[21:46:54] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[21:46:58] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[21:46:58] 
[21:46:58] Ignite node started OK (id=ae95174d)
[21:46:58] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=1, clients=2, CPUs=4, heap=4.4GB]
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Query execution failed: GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=ignite.MyIgniteBiPredicate@294a6b8e, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=false, subjId=ae95174d-ff1c-44b2-a7dc-24fab738729e, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1440)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$5.onHasNext(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:634)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy$2$1.onHasNext(IgniteCacheProxy.java:518)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.QueryCursorImpl.getAll(QueryCursorImpl.java:117)
    at ignite.SpringIgniteReceiverClient.main(SpringIgniteReceiverClient.java:31)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Query execution failed: GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=ignite.MyIgniteBiPredicate@294a6b8e, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=false, subjId=ae95174d-ff1c-44b2-a7dc-24fab738729e, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.checkError(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.internalIterator(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:318)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:164)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to execute query on node [query=GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=ignite.MyIgniteBiPredicate@294a6b8e, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=false, subjId=ae95174d-ff1c-44b2-a7dc-24fab738729e, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null], nodeId=366435c6-5fca-43dc-b1f2-5ff2b0d3ee2d]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.onPage(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryResponse(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:398)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.access$000(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:63)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$1.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$1.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:827)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$400(GridCacheIoManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$OrderedMessageListener.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1345)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1600(GridIoManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$GridCommunicationMessageSet.unwind(GridIoManager.java:2332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.unwindMessageSet(GridIoManager.java:1042)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1900(GridIoManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.run(GridIoManager.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: ignite.MyIgniteBiPredicate
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9785)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryRequest.finishUnmarshal(GridCacheQueryRequest.java:322)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.unmarshall(GridCacheIoManager.java:1298)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:364)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$000(GridCacheIoManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:238)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:673)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: ignite.MyIgniteBiPredicate
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:689)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:686)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1491)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:298)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:100)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9779)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ignite.MyIgniteBiPredicate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8393)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:185)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:680)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deploy `MyIgniteBiPredicate` on server nodes. Create a JAR file with this class and put this JAR into `IGNITE_HOME/libs` folder prior to cluster startup.